# How do i upload files into one colum to server using entity framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, row

How do I upload/save files in one row?

The code that I wrote is making two rows and leaving the other fields null then inserts into a new row other files in place of null values in the first row. Here is the image of what is being inserted in db:

[image]

Here is what I want things to be inserted like:

[image]

How do I make the code insert the files in one row after checking if the upload input has the files?

```
if (resume.HasFile == true && resume.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
{
    string fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(resume.FileName);
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(resume.FileName);
    string resumeName = "resume" + extension;

    BinaryReader Binary_Reader = new BinaryReader(resume.PostedFile.InputStream);
    byte[] File_Buffer = Binary_Reader.ReadBytes(resume.PostedFile.ContentLength);
    Binary_Reader = new BinaryReader(resume.PostedFile.InputStream);
    File_Buffer = Binary_Reader.ReadBytes(resume.PostedFile.ContentLength);
    myServiceCP.LicenseApplicationAttachments.Add(new LicenseApplicationAttachment
    {
        resumeName = resumeName,
        CompanyName = control.CompanyName,
        userid = Guid.NewGuid(),
        resumeContentType = resume.PostedFile.ContentType,
        resumeExtension = Path.GetExtension(resume.PostedFile.FileName),
        resumeSize = resume.PostedFile.ContentLength,
        resumeContent = File_Buffer
    });
}

if (cv.HasFile == true)
{
    string fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(cv.FileName);
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(cv.FileName);
    string cvFileName = "cv" + extension;

    BinaryReader Binary_Reader = new BinaryReader(cv.PostedFile.InputStream);
    byte[] File_Buffer = Binary_Reader.ReadBytes(cv.PostedFile.ContentLength);
    Binary_Reader = new BinaryReader(cv.PostedFile.InputStream);
    File_Buffer = Binary_Reader.ReadBytes(cv.PostedFile.ContentLength);
    myServiceCP.LicenseApplicationAttachments.Add(new LicenseApplicationAttachment
    {
        cvFileName = cvFileName,
        CompanyName = control.CompanyName,
        cvContentType = CapitalStructureShareHoldingFile.PostedFile.ContentType,
        cvExtension = Path.GetExtension(CapitalStructureShareHoldingFile.PostedFile.FileName),
        cvFileSize = CapitalStructureShareHoldingFile.PostedFile.ContentLength,
        cvFileContent = File_Buffer
    });
}    
myServiceCP.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: You would use an Insert into a table.  What is the table name and field?  Check database model.

Comment: @jdweng, i ddnt include it in the code because its already inserting but i want to combine that first if statement and the second to insert into a single column. Now its inserting the first if in a single row and leaving the other colums null then goes to the second statement and insert a second row and leave other fields (columns) null.

Comment: Why one column?  You would then need to split the two object (file and filename) when extracting.  If you only want one columns then you are putting an ASCII header on a binary file.  So you would need to use byte[] header Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("string" + "@");  I use the '@' character as a separator and then store both the file and header.  Use Binary_Reader.ReadBytes(header);

Comment: @jdweng, i have edited the post with the links of how things are being insert and how i expect them to be inserted.

Comment: You are going into both IF statements and creating two rows.  if (resume.HasFile == true && resume.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)   When HasFile == true and ContentLength > 0 both IF will be performed.

Comment: Yes they are performed and inserting data while creating two rows. i want to combine them so that they will insert into one row while checking checking if the file has something and length is > 0.

Comment: Make sure you only do one ADD then you will get only one row added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a variable and add the info you have to start,
then in your if statement add to your variable the info you need
Then add the variable to your database

Like this:

```
if (resume.HasFile == true && resume.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
{
    string fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(resume.FileName);
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(resume.FileName);
    string resumeName = "resume" + extension;

    BinaryReader Binary_Reader = new BinaryReader(resume.PostedFile.InputStream);
    byte[] File_Buffer = Binary_Reader.ReadBytes(resume.PostedFile.ContentLength);
    Binary_Reader = new BinaryReader(resume.PostedFile.InputStream);
    File_Buffer = Binary_Reader.ReadBytes(resume.PostedFile.ContentLength);

    var applicationToAdd = new LicenseApplicationAttachment
    {
        resumeName = resumeName,
        CompanyName = control.CompanyName,
        userid = Guid.NewGuid(),
        resumeContentType = resume.PostedFile.ContentType,
        resumeExtension = Path.GetExtension(resume.PostedFile.FileName),
        resumeSize = resume.PostedFile.ContentLength,
        resumeContent = File_Buffer
    };


    if (cv.HasFile == true)
    {
        string fileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(cv.FileName);
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(cv.FileName);
        string cvFileName = "cv" + extension;

        BinaryReader Binary_Reader = new BinaryReader(cv.PostedFile.InputStream);
        byte[] File_Buffer = Binary_Reader.ReadBytes(cv.PostedFile.ContentLength);
        Binary_Reader = new BinaryReader(cv.PostedFile.InputStream);
        File_Buffer = Binary_Reader.ReadBytes(cv.PostedFile.ContentLength);

        applicationToAdd.cvFileName = cvFileName;
        applicationToAdd.CompanyName = control.CompanyName;
        applicationToAdd.cvContentType = CapitalStructureShareHoldingFile.PostedFile.ContentType;
        applicationToAdd.cvExtension = Path.GetExtension(CapitalStructureShareHoldingFile.PostedFile.FileName);
        applicationToAdd.cvFileSize = CapitalStructureShareHoldingFile.PostedFile.ContentLength;
        applicationToAdd.cvFileContent = File_Buffer;

    } 
    myServiceCP.LicenseApplicationAttachments.Add(applicationToAdd);
    myServiceCP.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: but it worked with  `myServiceCP.LicenseApplicationAttachments.Add(applicationToAdd); ` on top of the curly brace